# Dual monitor connected to hdmi port not detecting on Dell Vostro 3750

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, 13.04, hdmi, dell-vostro

I am using Dell Vostro 3750 laptop with 2 monitors. OS Kubuntu 13.04

1 monitor I connected with VGA and it is working fine. But another monitor connected to HDMI port is not detected. I connected HDMI monitor to my friends laptop having Windows 7 and it works fine. but only with Ubuntu it is not working.

`lspci -v` output

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 525M] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: Dell Device 04c6
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
        Memory at f0000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
        Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
        I/O ports at 4000 [size=128]
        Expansion ROM at f1000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
        Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [78] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [b4] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
        Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
        Capabilities: [128] Power Budgeting <?>
        Capabilities: [600] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=024 <?>
        Kernel driver in use: nvidia
        Kernel modules: nvidia_current_updates, nvidia, nouveau, nvidiafb

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: Dell Device 04c6
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 51
        Memory at f1400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
        Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        I/O ports at 5000 [size=64]
        Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
        Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
        Capabilities: [a4] PCI Advanced Features
        Kernel driver in use: i915
        Kernel modules: i915
```

`xrandr` output

```
xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mm x 298mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+
   1680x1050      60.0  
   1600x900       60.0  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1280x800       59.8  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1280x720       60.0  
   1024x768       75.1     60.0  
   832x624        74.6  
   800x600        75.0     60.3  
   640x480        75.0     60.0  
   720x400        70.1
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you boot with the VGA unplugged and the HDMI plugged in?

Answer (score 0):

Select `Applications`->`System Tools`->`System Settings`->`Displays`

It should show you two Monitors and one laptop.

Click on Laptop and Select `Off`. Select Other two Monitors and select `On`. Click `Apply`.

http://s24.postimg.org/p1w3tyo5h/Screenshot_from_2013_04_28_09_36_06.png

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I am not able to see my two monitors and laptop display in Applications > system tools > system settings > displays.